# Why is this spider wound in such a dense web?

Tags: ecology, arachnology, arthropod

I saw this thing yesterday on my window curtain, and I've been wondering what this is. 
It looks like a dense network of spider web, and the spider inside it is visible. I thought the spider was dead, but I saw the spider making very small movements inside it. So, that made me more curious to know what it is.

[image]

Comment: This is probably made to protect eggs and young spiders, a sort of nest.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the spider outline, it looks to have short legs and is dark. A yellow sac spider is quite light-coloured and has long legs. Yellow sacs and clubionids will sometimes make themselves a sac for resting or eating or molting or laying eggs. Yours is probably a jumping spider, and here is a youtube timelapse video of a jumping spider laying eggs while inside its own protective sac:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoqMNX0RWuc